# Paypal custom reports Api

Tags: api, paypal

I need to get a custom report of the payments that we received in the last X (variable) days.

We use a PSP to handle our payments but they only store the amount of the original sales (not without the FEEAMT and currency conversion).

Important is that the report shows the amount that actually is ours, so:

- after the FEEAMT
- after currency conversion
- PAYMENTSTATUS must be "complete"

I cant find any working examples, only code snippets on https://developer.paypal.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) to pull orders within a time range, and then use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=gettransactiondetails) to pull specifics about any particular transaction.

If you are using PHP then you can use the [PHP SDK for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to make those calls very simple for you.